# Unable to open jar executable in windows

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

In windows 7, I accidentally made a "jar executable file" **open with** jar file. After which I couldn't open it as executable and it currently open as a jar file. 
How can I open it as jar executable. Please help me out with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with your `default program` of windows. You will have to set `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` if you want to run as jar executable. Check [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7) site, it will guide you to set the default program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get the latest JDK of java. Link below:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Good luck